# Revenue for two months date wise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get data for last 2 month ...but the query does not give perfect result....

```
    SELECT DAY(table_A.PaymentDate) as date1 , 
           (case when MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1
                 then CAST(SUM(table_A.Total_Amount) AS INT)  
                 else 0  
                 end) AS last_month_CNT, 
           (case when MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                 then CAST(SUM(table_A.Total_Amount) As INT) 
                 else 0  
                 end) as This_month_CNT  
    FROM   Tbl_Pan_Paymentdetails  table_A  
           FULL OUTER JOIN Tbl_Pan_Paymentdetails table_B 
                       ON table_A.PaymentDate=table_B.PaymentDate 
    WHERE  YEAR(table_A.PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
           AND
           table_A.PaymentDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())  
   GROUP BY 
           DAY(table_A.PaymentDate) ,MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) 
   order by 
           DAY(table_A.PaymentDate);
```

Comment: Use a better format please ...

Comment: I am try to get revenue for two months date wise to compare between two months,but with this query I get date twice repeated

Comment: You can't compare YEAR and MONTH separetely of each other, will run into problems around new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the entire case expression inside the sum function and don't include the month in the group by. Also, the full outer join seems unnecessary so I removed it.

This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  DAY(PaymentDate) as date1 ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-1 THEN CAST(Total_Amount AS INT) ELSE 0  END) AS last_month_CNT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)   THEN CAST(Total_Amount AS INT) ELSE 0  END) AS This_month_CNT 
FROM Tbl_Pan_Paymentdetails  
WHERE YEAR(PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND PaymentDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY  DAY(PaymentDate)
ORDER BY  DAY(PaymentDate);
```